# How do laravel policy methods with single arguments work?

Tags: laravel

I get perfectly how policies work when they take the principal and an object, like `$user->can('delete', $post)`, which will invoke PostPolicy::delete($user, $post) to determine the result.

What I don't get is how the methods like `viewAny` or `create` work, or how to test them.  I can't just say `$user->can('create')` now, can I?  Laravel's documentation is a maze sometimes (to say nothing of the source) and I haven't found anything on how to test policy methods by hand when they take only the single $user argument.

**EDIT:** As helpfully pointed out in the answer, just pass the class name.  It does come with one gotcha though: it must be the *original* class name, not an alias created with `class_alias()`, which is a common trick for tinker.  See here:

```php
>>> class_alias(\App\User::class, 'U')
=> true

>>> $u->can('viewAny', \App\User::class)
=> true

>>> $u->can('viewAny', U::class)
=> false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the class name as the second argument instead, that will determine which Policy is used for authorisation. For example if you want to ensure the `PostPolicy` is used, you can do the following.

```php
$user->can('create', App\Post::class);
```

From the Laravel documentation:

> As previously discussed, some actions like create may not require a model instance. In these situations, you should pass a class name to the authorize method. The class name will be used to determine which policy to use when authorizing the action.

Comment: I was going to reply that I'd tried that, then noticed you'd fully qualified the class name.  Apparently that's critical... as I'll explain in my amended post.

Comment: Yeah when using Tinker you would have to provide the FQCN due to the absent `use` statement.